# git message - what is a default configured remote for a given branch?

Tags: git

```
You asked to pull from the remote 'hub', but did not specify a branch.
Because this is not the default configured remote for your current
branch, you must specify a branch on the command line.
```

My question is: What does it mean by the following?

```
default configured remote for your current branch
```

We have a remote REPO configured.

Can anyone please clarify this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

each local branch can be configured to "track" a remote branch.
this means: whenever you pull the remote and updates occured on the remote-branch, git will try to update your local branch to include all the changesets from the remote one: if nothing happened on the local branch, it will just be fast-forwarded to the new tip of the remote branch; if you had local commits on the local branch, the two diverging branches will be merged.

otoh, there is no rule that says that your local branch must track a remote branch.
it's perfectly valid to have a local branch `foobar` and a remote branch `hub/foobar` which have nothing to do with each other.

the rule of thumb is:

- when *cloning* a remote repository, all remote branches (existing at the time of `clone`) will be *tracked* by the local branches by default
- when adding a new remote, no remote branches will be tracked by default

if you want to make a local branch follow a remote branch explicitely, i found it easiest to use the `-u` flag when pushing to the remote:

```
 git checkout localbranch
 git push -u <REMOTE>
```

Comment: What about this: `git branch branch_name --set-upstream-to hub/the_new_remote_branch_pushed_earlier` :) ? Does it makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Means what it says, you're trying to pull from the remote repo `hub` whereas the remote for the branch specified is something else. If you do `git branch -a` it'll show you what that branch is currently tracking in terms of a remote.

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
git remote -v
```

it will show the name of every remote plus the url of the associated git server.
Then,

```
git pull [REMOTE] master
```

should allow you to pull from the git server. [REMOTE] is the name you pick up from the previous command.

**EDIT**. I would like to add more detail. When you clone a git repository with `git clone [GIT_URL]`, git automatically configures a remote named `origin` associated with the `master` branch. Run `git pull` is equivalent to run `git pull origin master`, as well as `git push` is identical to `git push origin master`.
To come back to your question, you run `git pull hub`, but the default association remote-branch is `origin-master` so you probably have to run

```
git pull hub master
```

to get it work